# UNIX how to parse list of files in a directory more than once

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am working on a list of files in a directory.  I have already used awk to snip out specific fields.  Next I want to further cut-down the files.

My commands are
`ls /archive/gtx_rec_full | grep '2019-05-1' | awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8}' | more`

which returns a list like

> 9636502 2019-05-10 00:40 /archive/gtx_rec_full/GTX_20190608_1967_40431_236965.dat.gz
>   15915297 2019-05-10 01:39 /archive/gtx_rec_full/GTX_20190608_1967_40432_382768.dat.gz
>   10672671 2019-05-10 01:39 /archive/gtx_rec_full/GTX_20190608_1967_40433_261926.dat.gz
>   17362746 2019-05-10 02:41 /archive/gtx_rec_full/GTX_20190608_1967_40434_418702.dat.gz
>   13355381 2019-05-10 03:40 /archive/gtx_rec_full/GTX_20190608_1967_40435_323201.dat.gz

I want to keep the file sizes and timestamps, and then snip out the unique file IDs, like 40431, 40432, 40433, etc.  So, my new result set would look like:

```
9636502  05/10/2019 00:40   /archive/gtx_rec_full/40431
15915297 05/10/2019 01:39   /archive/gtx_rec_full/40432
10672671 05/10/2019 01:39   /archive/gtx_rec_full/40433
17362746 05/10/2019 02:41   /archive/gtx_rec_full/40434
13355381 05/10/2019 03:40   /archive/gtx_rec_full/40435
```

It is not clear to me how to do this.  Can anyone offer some suggestions?
Thank you!

I am working on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, 7.5

Comment: Use `split()` in `awk` to extract parts of the filename.

Comment: Your output doesn't match your command; `ls` (without `-l` ) won't give your sizes or dates ...

Comment: [Not that it's good practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse `ls` *at all*. Much better to use `stat` or `find -printf` when you need metadata; moreover, with `find`, you can just tell it to only return files with the date you want, rather than getting a much larger list and filtering it after-the-fact.

Comment: `grep ... | awk ...` is an anti-pattern.  `grep pattern | awk '{cmd}'` is better written `awk '/pattern/{cmd}'`

Comment: Do you also want the convert the layout of the date? Or is something like `| sed -r 's/GTX.*_(.*)_[^_]*/\1/ '` what you want?

Comment: @WalterA - I used sed to change the underscores to spaces, which really helped.  Thank you!

I do not know sed all that well; can I replace more than one delimiter with a single call to sed?  Or do I have to pipe my results through a 2nd sed call?  I want to also replace delimiter "/" with a space, so the entire output ends up being space delimited.

Comment: @WalterA -  actually I figured it out.  I can separate sed commands with a semi-colon.  So now it is working as I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your comment, you wanted

```
| sed -r 's/GTX.*_(.*)_[^_]*/\1/;s/\// /g'
```

(or, when you get confused by the slashes)

```
| sed -r 's#GTX.*_(.*)_[^_]*#\1#;s#/# #g'
```

When the solution you found is different, please post that one and accept your own answer.
Then everybody sees that the question is "finished".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
   id=$(awk -F_ '{ print $4 }' <<< "${line##*/}")
   path=$(awk '{ print $4 }' <<< "${line%/*}")
   newpath="$path/$id"
   echo "${newpath//\/*/}"
done < <(find /archive/gtx_rec_full -type f -name 'GTX_*' -printf "%-10s %Am/%Ad/%AY %AH:%AM   %p\n" -print0)
```